# With Which event I should replace my click event to pass eslint and stop event propagation?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, lint

html

```
<div (click)=addBtn($event)>Button</div>
```

.ts

```
addBtn(e:Event){
e.stopPropagation()
}
```

Its working fine but my code is getting failed while testing for eslint showing ,
"
click must be accompanied by either keyup, keydown or keypress event for accessibility  @angular-eslint/template/click-events-have-key-events.
"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a typescript method from your html button onclick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544752/calling-a-typescript-method-from-your-html-button-onclick-event)

Comment: nope, its not working with this way too

Comment: What is your question? do you want to change this `(click)` event? can you elaborate more..

Comment: Also you have typo there. It's `stopPropagation` not `stopPropagtion `

Comment: I just missed it here , while posting the query

Comment: eslint error makes sense since your element is not ADA compliant, anyways you can either disable the error with a comment or better you can convert the div into a button
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59407526/9016028

Comment: try maybe adding keyup method, which will along with click method serve to call addBtn.. see (for inspiration): https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/main/docs/rules/click-events-have-key-events.md